# Cloud9- Debugger Listening on Port 15454?

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, javascript-debugger

I have been trying to run a JavaScript file on the BeagleBone Black (Cayenne radar module) and I keep getting the message

Debugger Listening on Port 15454

when I run the js file on the cloud9 ide, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? [This is the image of the message when I run the js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBlyZ.jpg)

Comment: which version of the ide do you use? (it is in cloud9>about cloud9 menu)

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in old versions of cloud9, sometime the proxy process gets stuck, and you need to kill it manually:

- stop the runner
- use the following snippet to kill all programs listening on 15454

  ```
  ids=`sudo lsof -ti :15454 `; 
  echo $ids; 
  sudo kill -9 $ids;
  ```
- start the runner